# Can you use wirsbo/uponor/expansion pex for underground sprinklers?

Tags: pex, irrigation

I cant find much information around this online, it appears that its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to pex all types, some sources:

- https://www.landscapemanagement.net/benefits-of-evolving-irrigation-pipe-products-2/
- http://blog.supplyhouse.com/pex-crimp-vs-pex-clamp/
- http://blog.supplyhouse.com/direct-burial-of-pex-tubing

Comment: I have been told that PEX crimp connections cannot be in soil contact because the copper or brass crimp bands corrode and fail. PEX A Upponor can be in soil contact.

Comment: Hi Jim, read: http://blog.supplyhouse.com/pex-crimp-vs-pex-clamp/ and http://blog.supplyhouse.com/direct-burial-of-pex-tubing/ even the pex itself has a service life, it's all about choices. If OP were asking to compare the various types, I could see going into that, but my answer stands unqualified.

Comment: It would help if you could include a few salient points from one or more of the linked sources. Posts do tend to disappear (either taken down or sites rearranged), and that makes this answer useless in the future. That's why "link only" is a reason for deleting an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm good. This was a yes or no question. I answered that with a yes, then offered some further reading for OP to do some legwork. The links are tangential to the substantive point of the answer. My opinion is you two are critiquing my answer for a problem with this forum permitting yes/no questions... Jimmy fix-it has sets precedent in my opinion - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/223913/can-i-plaster-over-metal-lath-without-a-backing-material/223928#223928 - See his comments and massively higher approval points...

Comment: Good call on the sources, I also saw that in the second source they talk about stainless crimp bands for underground applications. But luckily all I needed was the OK for uponor.

Comment: I agree with @FreeMan

Comment: It's not an "opinion" about the links - it's a [site rule](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) (scroll down to the "Provide context for links" heading). If you don't like it, that's fine, you're not required to. If you chose not to follow it, well, you might find answers getting deleted for being "link only". Based on your answer, should those links die, all we have is your (very short) word for it. I'm not doubting you, but providing supporting info makes your answer more credible.